# Deploy angular 8 and django rest framework

Tags: django, angular, nginx, heroku, django-rest-framework

I have successfully deployed django rest framework backend and angular 8 frontend apps independently on Heroku. I'm clueless whether they should be deployed as separate apps or should be integrated on single instance. What is the best practice when it comes to DRF and SPA,particularly angular? If to be deployed as independent app,how can I configure DRF backend to respond to the frontend in another server. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks